# OpenApi Codegen CLI Java Client - How to inject header properly?

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm using open-api to communication between some java microservices and it works fine, I just facing some situation that I cannot found the proper way to solve: how inject a header in ApiClient.authentications map in the java before call the microservice that will validate(since it is unmodifiable, i think because [it was not thread safe](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/1435)).
I wanna do it to try use the global authorization configuration (existing in documentation link below).

The yaml structure is the below [using this documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/api-keys/) (applied in both microservices):

[image]

I saw [this topic of a override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39724076/swagger-codegen-cli-java-client-how-to-use-it-right), but I hope have a better approach, also like I mention, I need it as a header, not as a parameter inside of methods.

Obs: It must me a header, not a parameter (that is usually the workaround) (different issue, that looks have some time and still not solve, so [I create a new question](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/Swagger-Open-Source-Tools/API-key-security-not-imported-from-Swagger-OAS-RIA-12389-still/td-p/247743))

[image]

So, I'm trying to see if have a proper way to inject that header I need without override the **ApiClient**. I tried extend that and just remove the **unmodifiableMap** from the **init()** (image above), but still was not enough.

How I can do it properly? Thanks in advance.